# Using TL431/ATL431 to make UV lockout circuit for gate driver IC

Tags: power, analog, gate-driving, undervoltage, tl431

I am using UCC5350 (isolated gate driver) in 3 phase bridge circuit, sadly I decided later in the project to use isolated Bipolar dc/dc converter MGJ2D241509SC (+15/-9) for gate drive supply. 15 V connected to VDD and -9 V to VEE and Switch-node will connect to 0 V pin of the DC/DC converter. Now the problem is that this gate driver is not optimized for bipolar supply and UVLO is too low. Since I bought a large quantity and I cannot change the gate driver, I have to implement UVLO externally to prevent Turn On when Supply is not ready (dc/dc output rise time is about 3 ms). UVLO should be around 90% of supply. If monitoring VCC-VEE UVLO=~22 V. If VCC to Sw. UVLO=~14 V.

1. Do you have any suggestion on a simple circuit other than using ATL431 and its derivatives?
2. What would be better, using ATL431 to control P-channel MOSFET to turn off gate driver supply OR using ATL431 to control an opto coupler which controls a buffer or AND gate to disable PWM inputs?
3. What would be better monitoring the total output of dc/dc converter (across VDD-VEE), or just the positive voltage? I am worried that switch node undershoot and noise could cause false triggering ATL431.
4. Can I add capacitor and is there a limit on maximum value near Feedback/Ref pin of ATL431Li? the goal is to filter the switching noise and prevent false triggering.

Comment: Please add which UVLO voltages you want.

Comment: A schematic would help.

Comment: There are quite a few design examples of UVLO in this [link](https://www.powerctc.com/en/node/4251). If you go for a discrete solution, do not forget to add hysteresis to these circuits, it is important for a reliable operation. In my opinion, stay away from UVLO built around TL431: the part operates reliably in linear mode but I have seen many problems when you want to use it as a comparator.

Comment: optocoupler? why?  which UCC5330 variant? VCC  and VEE  are not terminals on the UCC53x0. please clarify

Comment: REF voltage, if it goes much over 2.5 you're doing it wrong. there is a maximum of 10mA allowed into the REF terminal. treat it as a BJT  base.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні , the S variant . it has pins VCC2 and VEE2 which are the power side